# Split items of different width in a fixed number of rows

Tags: algorithm

Basically, suppose I have 5 items with the following widths (the height doesn't really matter for this, so let's just say they all have a height of 50 pixels):

1. 50
2. 100
3. 100
4. 100
5. 50

And I want to split them in 2 different rows as even as possible (it has to be in that order). How can I calculate the minimal width of the rows to do this?

**NOTE**: It's not as simple as adding up all the widths and dividing it by the number of rows, if you do that with the example above, the items won't fit because the sum of the widths (400) divided by the number of rows (2) is 200 (400 / 2 = 200), in which case, the fifth item won't fit in any of the rows.

Here's another example that won't work if by using the method I just mentioned:

1. 100
2. 50
3. 100
4. 50
5. 50
6. 50

In this case, the last two items (5 and 6) would need an extra row.

A C# sample would be really nice since it's the language I'm using to do this =).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want exactly two rows, or do you want a solution for an arbitrary (but fixed) number of rows?

Comment: "As even as possible", does that mean minimize the function `f = widestRowWidth - narrowestRowWidth` ?

Comment: @TedHopp 4 rows in the project I'm working on. It will always be 4 rows. I said 2 for simplicity.

Comment: So you said 2 rows "for simplicity" and I posted an answer that works for 2 rows but is useless for 4 rows. How did that simplify anything? In the future, please ask the question that you actually want answered.

Comment: @TedHopp Well, I didn't think there would be a difference between 2 or 4 or 10 for that matter.

Comment: Why shouldn't (400/2)=200 in both cases work? a: (1,2,5)(3,4), b: (1,2,4)(3,5,6). What am I missing?

Comment: @userunknown - The order of items needs to be preserved.

Comment: So he doesn't want to distribute, but the split them/partition. So build the middle (200), and chose either the value below or above that threshold. Both examples lead to a 150/250 or 250/150 decision. Not a good example, because both are even good or bad.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that you are trying to fit `N` items of widths `{W[i]}` in `R` rows of width `C`; your `R` is fixed, your `C` is unknown.

First, let's make a few important observations:

- Given a `C`, it is easy to *check* if choosing that particular `C` makes your arrangement into exactly `R` rows: you can do it by going over the items one by one, calculating the running total, and using `C` as your cutoff point.
- The minimum value of `C` is the smallest `W[i]`; the maximum is the total of `W[i]`s
- Increasing `C` can make the number of rows required for that `C` go down, but it cannot make it go up; hence, the function `RequiredRows(C, W[0..N])` is *monotonic*.

These observations lead to a simple algorithm: run a binary search for the smallest `C` such that  `RequiredRows(C, W[0..N]) == R` by running a checker based on the running total at each step of the binary search.

Here is a skeletal implementation in C#:

```
private static int RequiredRows(int C, int[] data) {
    var res = 1;
    var total = 0;
    foreach ( var w in data) {
        if (total+w <= C) {
            total += w;
        } else {
            res++;
            total = w;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
public static void Main() {
    var data = new[] {50,100,100,100,50};
    var R = 2;
    var start = data.Max();
    var end = data.Sum();
    while (start+1 < end) {
        var mid = start+((end-start)/2);
        if (RequiredRows(mid, data) > R) {
            start = mid;
        } else {
            end = mid;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(end);
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Note that the width of the smallest item is the smallest change in C that needs to be considered when doing a binary search.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't computing the running total take linear time, defeating the purpose of the binary search?

Comment: @larsmans No, because the two searches are performed in different spaces. The linear search is done in the space of `0..N`, where `N` is the number of items. The binary search is done in the space of `max(W[i])..sum(W[i])`, where `W[i]` is the width of the item number `i`. So the running time is `O(N*Log(sum(W)))`.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is fixed and there are exactly two rows, this is a fairly easy problem. Convert your array of widths into a cumulative array. For the first example, it would be:

1. 50
2. 150
3. 250
4. 350
5. 400

For the second it would be:

1. 100
2. 150
3. 250
4. 300
5. 350
6. 400

Then just search for the entry that is closest to half the last entry and divide the list in two just after that entry. Resolve ties arbitrarily (so, either after item 2 or 3 in either example). The minimum row width is then the maximum of the entry cumulative width or the difference between that and the total width (the last cumulative entry).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where you want two rows. You can just test all of the possible split points (indexes) in the list and see which one yields the best result (minimize the maximum row width).

For more than two rows, just use recursion to continue splitting the "right-half" as shown in the code sample below. (Python)

```
def split(sizes, count):
    # base case: one row, just return it
    if count == 1:
        return [sizes]
    best_score = None
    best_result = None
    # for each possible split point (don't allow empty rows)
    for i in range(1, len(sizes)):
        # the first row is the columns up to the split point
        left = [sizes[:i]]
        # recurse to process the remaining rows
        right = split(sizes[i:], count - 1)
        if right is None:
            # failed to split count - 1 times, ignore
            continue
        rows = left + right
        # minimize the maximum row width
        score = max(sum(row) for row in rows)
        if best_score is None or score < best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_result = rows
    return best_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sizes = [100, 50, 100, 50, 50, 50]
    print split(sizes, 2)
    print split(sizes, 3)
```

Output:

```
[[100, 50], [100, 50, 50, 50]] # 2 rows
[[100], [50, 100], [50, 50, 50]] # 3 rows
```

Comment: `[[100, 50], [100, 50, 50, 50]]` isn't quite the optimal solution.

Comment: It's 250 wide. Which ties with the next choice: `[[100, 50, 100], [50, 50, 50]]`. The algorithm yields the first of the ties.

Comment: I will give this a shot, I'm not really familiar with Python, hopefully it will be easy to translate to C#. Thanks!

Comment: But the optimal solution would be `[[100, 100], [50] * 4]`.

Comment: @FogleBird There is a TopCoder user with the same handle :)

Comment: @larsmans: He said "it has to be in that order" so I assume you cannot rearrange items.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That's me. :)

Comment: @FogleBird: excuse me, overlooked that!

Comment: @FoggleBird aah yeah we can't re-arrange the items, is that going to affect the algorithm?

Comment: @FogleBird There was a similar problem in one of the early SRMs (I think it was about stacking items a certain height, and finding the optimal solution). I cannot find it in the archives because the problem statements from the early archives seem to be unavailable.

Comment: @Carlo, no, my algorithm does not rearrange anything, just like you said.